# Finding multidimensional array pattern for every odd j index

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok, so I'm trying to insert a space character for every odd number of j (including 0), the problem is that 0 counts as an even number (I want it to count as odd so a space character can be placed) and I'm struggling with how to figure out a solution other than playing with odd or even j. The goal is to make every element in the array have a letter and have a space character for the next index. This function is responsible for filling up the array.

```
void createBoard(char arr [DIM][DIM], int size){
  //ASCII number for capital A
  char x = 65;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){
      if(j%2==0){
        arr[i][j] = x++;
      }
      else{
     arr[i][j] = 32;
      }
 cout << "Element at x[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
          cout << arr[i][j] << endl;

  }
  
  }
}
```

This is function main.

```
const int DIM = 7;
int main()
{
char arr [DIM][DIM];
int bsize;
char answer;
do{
        cout << "Please enter the size of the board [1-7]: ";
        cin >> bsize;
        if(!cin){
            cout << endl << "Invalid entry";
            break;
        }
        if (bsize<=DIM && bsize>=1){
    createBoard(arr,bsize);
        }
        else{
        cout << endl << "Invalid size";
        cout << endl << "Do you want to try again [y-n]?: ";
        cin >> answer;
        }
// As long as the answer is 'y' (in upper or lower case), keep looping      
}while(answer=='Y'||answer=='y');
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char x = 'A'` would avoid the need for that comment.

Comment: `if(j%2==0 && j != 0) ...`. This effectively "counts 0 as odd number"